# Changing a column of a DataFrame row subset

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'text':['foo', '10€', 'EUR5', 'bar'], 'x':[1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]})

    text    x
0   foo     1.1
1   10€     2.2
2   EUR5    3.3
3   bar     4.4
```

which I subset using a regex in the following way:

```
df_amounts = df.loc[df.text.str.contains(r"(EUR|€)?\d+(EUR|€)?")]

    text    x
1   10€     2.2
2   EUR5    3.3
```

From now on I only use the subset and do not care about the original df (I actually do not want to change it!). Which leads me to the question if I can ignore the warning (and possibly turn it off) that happens when I do the following:

```
df_amounts.loc[:, 'text'] = df_amounts.text.str.strip("EUR€")

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I have read the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) and I think I am doing the assignment the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df_amounts = df.loc[df.text.str.contains(r"(EUR|€)?\d+(EUR|€)?")].copy()
df_amounts['text'] = df_amounts.text.str.strip("EUR€")
print (df_amounts)
  text    x
1   10  2.2
2    5  3.3
```

If you modify values in `df_amounts` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df`), and that Pandas does warning.

Comment: But isn't that (the creation of a copy) what's happening implicitly without `copy()` at the line `df_amounts.loc[:, 'text'] = df_amounts.text.str.strip("EUR€")` ?

Comment: @MoRe - No, problem is above, `df_amounts.loc[:, 'text'] = df_amounts.text.str.strip("EUR€")` only modify filtered data, so warning.

Comment: Same problem is if use `df_amounts['x'] /= 2`